# computer cant find the right folder

Tags: c#, file, path

im using c# in my web. i m trying to upload a video in my website and im almost succed but the computer go to folder'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\' insted of just C:\Users\Omer\source\repos\WebApplication12\WebApplication12\potg. im using the function  Server.MapPath(folder) and yet its dont work. help pls?

c#

```
string path = "";
        MyVideoHelper x = new MyVideoHelper();
            bool deleteFile = false;
            if ((video2.PostedFile != null) && (video2.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0))
            {
                path =x.SaveFileInFoder(video2.PostedFile, "potg", Server);
                deleteFile = true;  
            }
        string potg = "potg";
        string command = "INSERT INTO videos (file) VALUES('"+x.ConvertFileToByte(potg)+"')";
        MyAdoHelper.DoQuery("omerwatchdb.accdb", command);
            Response.Redirect("potg.aspx");
            Response.End();
            if ((deleteFile) && (File.Exists(path))){File.Delete(path);}
```

library:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;

public class MyVideoHelper
{
    public MyVideoHelper()
    {

    }

    public  byte[] ConvertFileToByte(string location)
    {
        byte[] video = null;

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(location, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        video = br.ReadBytes((int)(fs.Length));

        return video;
    }
    public  string SaveFileInFoder(HttpPostedFile file, string folder, HttpServerUtility Server)
    {
        string location;

        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            location = Server.MapPath(folder) + "\\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

            try
            {
                file.SaveAs(location);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                location = ex.Message;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            location = null;
        }

        return location;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure I'm understanding your question. `Server.MapPath` returns this because the web site is published under that location. If you want to save in another place why do you use MapPath?

Comment: @derloopkat  in my website i have a folder named potg i that the file that user was upload will go to that folder

Comment: Why using `Server.MapPath` at all? Why don't you rely on your root folder. If you want to save your file in root folder just target it as `myfile.ext`. Since that would be total mess do it like this `SomeFolderName/myfile.ext` and it will  automatically access your `rootFolder/SomeFolderName` and save file there.

Comment: @AleksaRistic beacuse i need this work at every computer. what r u think i need to do?

Comment: You are uploading file (video) to your web server. Your problem is when user upload it, it uploads to location you do not want to. Is this right?

Comment: @AleksaRistic yes!